# How to ask turtles to walk over a particular path of network among many networks using Link primitives

Tags: netlogo

I have created network of paths using links primitive and then created turtles(people in my code) which walks on these links. My code is running fine. In this code a random network of link-node is created each time the setup module is called and simultaneously turtles are created on random nodes. They start walking when go procedure is called.

Now i want to create two or more fixed path network say for example Network A and Network B and then to create people in any one network that is network A with all people over it and Network B with no people over it, when setup is called. how can this be done? Since in current code people are being created in both networks as shown in the attached figure for reference. I am also writing my full code for your ease to understand.

[image]

```
breed [ nodes node ]
breed [ people person ]

people-own [ to-node cur-link previous-link speed cur-location]

to setup
    clear-all
    ask patches [set pcolor pink]

    setup-nodeslinks
    setup-people

   reset-ticks
end

to setup-nodeslinks
   set-default-shape nodes "circle"
   ;; create a random network
   create-nodes 30 [ set color blue ]
   ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
   ;; lay it out so links are not overlapping
   repeat 500 [ layout ]
   ;; leave space around the edges
   ask nodes [ setxy 0.95 * xcor 0.95 * ycor ]
end

to layout
   layout-spring nodes links 0.5 2 1
end

;; put some "people" turtles on the network

to setup-people
   set-default-shape people "person"
   let people-size 1
   let max-speed  (max-speed-km/h / 36) / 8.775
   let min-speed  max-speed * (1 - speed-variation) 
   create-people num-people [
      set size people-size ;; use meters-per-patch??
      set color yellow
      set speed min-speed + random-float (max-speed - min-speed)
      let l one-of links
      set-next-person-link l [end1] of l
      set previous-link l
    ]
 end

 to set-next-person-link [l n] ;;  proc
   set cur-link l
   move-to n
   set cur-location n
    ifelse n = [end1] of l [set to-node [end2] of l] [set to-node [end1] of  l]
   face to-node
end

to go
   ask people [move-people speed]

   tick 
end

to move-people [spd] ;; people move proc
    let distfromnode distance to-node
    ifelse distfromnode > spd
    [
        ask one-of people-here[if any? other people-here with [precision heading 3 = [precision heading 3] of myself]
                           [ let d min-one-of people-here [[distancexy xcor ycor] of myself]
                             set speed [speed] of d
                           ]
                         ]
         forward spd
     ]
     [ routedirection
       move-people spd - distfromnode ]
 end

  to routedirection
      set previous-link cur-link
      let nextlinks [my-links] of to-node
      ifelse count nextlinks = 1 [ set-next-person-link one-of nextlinks to- node ]
                            [ set-next-person-link one-of nextlinks with  [self != [cur-link] of myself] to-node ]
  end
```

Comment: Please, can any one help, It will be a great help for me.

Comment: look at the NetLogo Network extension http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html
And especially the `nw:weak-component-clusters` primitive, which helps you to identify the different components of your network

Comment: Thank You @Tyr , but I couldn't found what exactly i need. If you please provide any link for code example. The logic is that I want to keep the single list of links of network in two different set of list so that I can command or use these list individually as and when needed.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe you could just give the nodes a component variable (nodes-own [component])? Then during setup you could create x nodes with component = "A" and y nodes with component = "B". Then when you connect the nodes, connect them only with one random node of the same type ('ask nodes [create-link-with one-of other nodes with [component = [component] of myself]]'). You can assign the component indicator to the links as well. Then you can easily filter the sets of nodes and links.

Comment: ok, thats great I will try. Thank You so much.